# Add linear gradient color to switch component

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

How can I add linear gradient color to a `Switch` in react-native?
I can use `Switch` from either `react-native` or `react-native-paper` but I'm open to other dependencies as well.
This is what I'm expecting:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the react native switch does not support the gradient background.

This is how I implemented the switch gradient using [react-native-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-switch) and [react-native-linear-gradient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient)

```
const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

    <LinearGradient
      start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
      end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
      colors={['#F95D09', '#F9B21D']}
      style={{borderRadius: 14}}>
      <Switch
        circleBorderWidth={0}
        circleSize={12}
        value={check}
        onValueChange={() => setCheck(!check)}
        activeText={''}
        inActiveText={''}
        backgroundActive={'transparent'}
        backgroundInactive={'#6080A0'}
        switchBorderRadius={14}
        switchLeftPx={2}
        switchRightPx={2}
        barHeight={20}
        switchWidthMultiplier={3}
      />
    </LinearGradient>
```

The main idea is to make the track color **trasparent** with the switch wrapped inside linear-gradient.
You can see the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLqQX.png)